# App engine xml sync with Android

Tags: android, xml, google-app-engine, xml-parsing

I'm attempting to build a sort of contact list that is stored in the google app engine and then can be accessed and edited on android devices.

I've started by creating an app engine helloworld type project. Any ideas on how to code the engine side so that it can add xml entries to a file? I will then use the url with the xml entries to parse the contacts from the engine and display them on the phone.

I won't have any problem parsing the xml with the android app to build the contacts list on the mobile device.

Comment: Have you chosen the persistence model for App Engine? What code have you started with? Are you using python, java, or another language on GAE?

Comment: @MiStr Java is all I know. I'm not really familiar with the whole cloud aspect of things. I will be uploading xml entries to the cloud and would like the app engine add the entries to a list that can be retrieved later back on mobile devices.

Comment: Why require XML to be sent to GAE? Just send the strings/fields, and store them in an object in GAE. Take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

Comment: @MiStr This looks like the right thing. Thanks!

Comment: Added an official answer so that this question can be marked as answered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may benefit from using a different (less verbose) mechanism for storing your data on Google's App Engine (GAE).

Here is the [GAE Documentation for the Java Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/). It takes a bit of time to review, but gives you the options for storage.